# if $Ax=b$ has a solution for all $b$ then $A^Tx=b$ also has a solution for all $b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A\in M_{m\times n}(F)$
>   Prove/Disprove: If $Ax=b$ has a solution for all $b$ then $A^Tx=b$ also has a solution for all $b$

I was gonna say "Yes", for the case $A$ is a square matrix (Since, $A$ has a solution for all $b$, $A$ is invertible and therefore, $A^T$ is also invertible and therefore has a solution for all $b$).

But, I think I should find a counter-example where $m\ne n$.
I'd be glad for a direction/idea.

Thanks

Comment: See what happens with $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true in general, take an example:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$ For every $b = (b_1,b_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ we have 
$$  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}= b,$$
but there is clearly no $x=(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that
$$  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \\ 0& 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the $n\times n $ square matrix, it is true: notice that if $Ax = b$ has solution for all $b$, then $A$ must be invertible since its image must be all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $\det A=\det A^T$, $A^T$ must also be invertible hence $A^Tx=b$ has a solution for all $b$ (namely, $x = (A^T)^{-1}b$).